# Images not appearing in PFQueryCollectionViewController

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uicollectionview, pfimageview

I'm working on an iPhone app that should display images in a `UICollectionView`. The images are saved on the Parse cloud, and I'm using a subclass of `PFQueryCollectionViewController` to make the query and display the images.

Tapping on a `MKMapView` callout triggers the segue that shows the `CollectionViewController`. The images do not appear in the cells the first time the `CollectionViewController` is presented. However, if I go back to the `MapView`, and then return to the `CollectionViewController`, the images appear in the cells.

How can I get the images to appear the first time the `PFQueryCollectionViewController` is presented?

Here's my code:

```
class PhotoGridCollectionViewController: PFQueryCollectionViewController {

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
  super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
  // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
  //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of sections
  return 1
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of items in the section
  return self.objects.count
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFCollectionViewCell? {

  let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("venuePhotoThumb", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PhotoGridCollectionViewCell

  if let pfObject = object {
    cell.imageView.file = pfObject["imageFile"] as? PFFile
    cell.imageView.loadInBackground({ (img, err) -> Void in
      println("Download complete")
    })
  }

  return cell
}

}
```

Since I'm using Storyboards, I pass my custom class the `parseClass` by setting it in the Attribute Inspector:

[image]

As you can see, I'm using the `loadInBackground` method of the `PFImageView` to load the images asynchronously, and I think this the problem might be caused by the images being downloaded after the cell is returned, but I don't have any other ideas. Does anyone know why the images are not appearing the first time the view is presented?

Comment: When does it log Download complete ?

Comment: The strange thing is that Download Complete is logged instantly after the view is presented, and it appears in the console the correct number of times for the number of objects in my Parse cloud storage. However, if I set breakpoints at `return cell` and `println("Download complete")`, I can see that when I first show the view, the cells are returned before download completes, but if I leave the view and return, download completes before the cells are returned.

Comment: That is to be expected, the image should update on the cell once it's ready. Try logging the image and error and, not that you should need to, but setting the image yourself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My co-developer finally found the answer to this. We had to set a placeholder image for the `PFImageViews` when configuring the cells in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`. The code examples on Parse do include setting the placeholder image, but they don't say that it is required for the `PFQueryCollectionViewController` to work properly. We considered it an aesthetic touch that we could come back to later.

So the answer is: in order for images to load properly in the cells of a `PFQueryCollectionViewController` you MUST provide a placeholder image when configuring the cells in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`.

Here's the code that worked:

```
let placeholder = UIImage(named: "myPlaceholderImage")  //an image from images.xcassets in your xcode project
cell.imageView.image = placeholder

if let pfObject = object {
    cell.imageView.file = pfObject["image"] as? PFFile
    cell.imageView.loadInBackground()
}
```

Comment: This helped, thanks! However, I think the code is:


`cell?.imageView.image = placeholder`

Comment: Glad my answer helped! It drove my co-worker an I crazy. I edited the answer to fix the mistake you caught.